# Найти продолжительность сессии (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Исходные данные:**

- status - статус сессии: 'invoked' - запуск сессии, 'dismissed' -
  завершение
- source_name - имя компьютера/пользователя
- time - время события

**Задача:** посчитать среднее время сессии.
**Сложность** в том, что не про каждую сессию указано и начало, и завершение, бывает так, что у одного пользователя идет подряд два открытия и одно закрытие (пример на картинке).

[image: Данные]

То есть обязательно нужно группировать по имени, и тут возникает проблема с индексами(

**Пример.** Хотела проверить на одном имени: если первая строка - открытие сессии, а вторая - закрытие, то вычесть из второй первую:

```
name = data[data['Source_name']=='WOD-0000000']
for i in name:
    if (name['Status'][i]=='invoked') and (name['Status'][i+1]=='dismissed'):
        name['lag'][i] = name['Time'][i+1] - name['Time'][i]
```

Выдает ошибку `KeyError: 'Status'`.

Пыталась написать вложенные циклы с двумя for:

```
for name in data['Source_name']:
    for i in data:
        if (name['Status'][i]=='invoked') and (name['Status'][i+1]=='dismissed'):
            name['lag'][i] = name['Time'][i+1] - name['Time'][i]
```

Но он считает тогда слишком долго (там более 200 к строк), и, кажется, есть вариант попроще.

С функцией тоже пыталась, но не поняла, какие переменные нужны (name или i) и как ее выстроить правильно.

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: пример данных должен быть в воспроизводимом виде и более представительным. вы не указали формат данных - это pandas dataframe?

Comment: Да, pandas dataframe

Comment: Как его сделать воспроизводимым? Форматы все правильные - в датах - даты, в названиях - строки

Comment: в текстовом виде добавьте. или файл выложите в файлообменник или на гугл докс

Comment: Если среднее посчитать как дельту между первым временем и последним в группе, деленное на кол-во dismissed? Это, конечно, ну будет идеально точно, но с учетом а) незакрытых сессий, б) многократно открытых сессий, мне кажется, что такая погрешность будет вполне допустимой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, можно сделать так (разумеется, принимаем за аксиому, что колонка Time у вас имеет тип datetime):

```
df["session"] = df.sort_values("Time").groupby("Source_name")["Status"].apply(
    lambda x: (x=="dismissed").cumsum().shift().fillna(0)).reset_index(0)["Status"]
res = df.groupby(["Source_name", "session"])["Time"].apply(
    lambda x:x.max()-x.min() if len(x)>1 else None)
```

res:

```
Source_name   session
-WOD-0000000  0.0       0 days 01:45:48
              1.0       0 days 00:00:04
-WOD-0000005  0.0       0 days 00:00:02
-WOD-0000017  0.0                   NaT
-WOD-0000019  0.0                   NaT
              1.0                   NaT
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Т. е. сортируем по времени и группируем датафрейм по колонке Source_name, и в новой колонке session формируем флаги непрерывных сессий пользователя, на основании колонки Status, пока после скольких угодно invoked не встретится dismissed.

Потом уже получившийся фрейм группируем по пользователю и сессии и вычисляем продолжительность. при этом сессии, в которых dismissed был раньше invoked или незакрытые сессии будут иметь единичную длину и не будут учитываться, возвращая NaT

P.S. Если честно. мне кажется, что можно сделать как-то покороче, но у меня нет особо времени вникать.